# How to programmatically "tap" UITableview cell when only one result is shown in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app that shows search results from a search bar in a UItableview. Currently, the user must tap on one of the search results in order for a segue to occur. What I want to do is make it so that if the search results only show one result, the segue happens automatically. Below is my current code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ProductViewController
        let product:Product!
        if(isSearchActive){
            product = filterProducts[(tblProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        } else {
            product = products[(tblProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
        vc.product = product
    }
}

extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(isSearchActive){
            return filterProducts.count
        }
        return products.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    let product:Product!
    if(isSearchActive){
        product = filterProducts[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        product = products[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.initUI(product)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoProduct", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your searcher is reloading your tableview correctly, you can just put the check inside of your delegate method; when the tableview checks the row count, if you are search and there is one result, then perform the segue.

```
extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{ 
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(isSearchActive){
      if filterProducts.count == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoProduct", sender: self)
      }
      return filterProducts.count 
    } 
    return products.count 
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when using your suggested code: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 0):

```
extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(isSearchActive){
            if self.isRedirected == false {
                self.isRedirected = true
                if self.filterProducts.count == 1{
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) { [unowned self] in
                        self.tblProducts.selectRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoProduct", sender: self)
                    }
                }
            }
            return filterProducts.count
        }
        return products.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
        let product:Product!
        if(isSearchActive){
            product = filterProducts[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            product = products[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.initUI(product: product)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoProduct", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your suggested code, but the segue continues to auto repeat itself instead of just doing the one segue

Comment: I have updated the number of row in section method , define a variable var isRedirected : Bool = false in view controller and set it to false every time you reload the table view